# How to get EXPLICIT listProperties (not Infered properties) of a Resource with Jena

Tags: java, jena

I'm using this family ontology (www.cs.man.ac.uk/~stevensr/ontology/family.rdf.owl) where I've deleted all the existing individuals. 
By using Jena, I've added 02 instances "paul" and "sara" to the class Person and states that sara is the sister of paul.

```
String u = "http://www.co-ode.org/roberts/family-tree.owl#";
String path = "src/main/resources/family.rdf.owl" ;

OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
model.read(path);

OntClass c = model.getOntClass(u + "Person");
Individual s = c.createIndividual(u + "Sara");
Individual p = c.createIndividual(u+"Paul");
model.add(s, model.getObjectProperty(u+"isSisterOf"), p);
StmtIterator stmtIterator = s.listProperties();
stmtIterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

The `s.listProperties()` returns the statement `sara isSisterOf paul` but also, `sara isDirectSiblingOf paul`, `sara isSiblingOf paul`, `sara isBloodRelationOf paul`, `sara isRelationOf paul`
it seems as `Resource.listProperties()` also returns INDIRECT properties, since isSisterOf is a subproperty of the others. I only want the relation I explicitly stated `sara isSisterOf paul`, not the entailed ones.

Comment: You are doing something wrong: `Resource#listProperties` returns only DIRECT statements.Most of methods returns direct things without any magic, only `OntClass#listInstances(boolean)` looks at the hierarchy. Please provide full snipped, e.g.  `OntClass c = m.getOntClass(u + "Person"); Individual s = c.createIndividual(u + "Sara"); Individual p = c.createIndividual(u+"Paul"); m.add(s, m.getObjectProperty(u+"isSisterOf"), p);s.listProperties().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);`

Comment: Snippet, starting with loading from web, not after editing by protege. And please don't delete comments/answers, otherwise no one will help

Comment: The family ontology is imported in another one called Domus.
`OntClass contactClass = model.getOntClass(Ontology.FAMILY_URI + "Person");
Individual sara = contactClass.createIndividual(Ontology.DOMUS_URI + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
model.add(sara, RDFS.label, "Sara");
/* same for paul*/
ObjectProperty relationProperty = model.getObjectProperty(Ontology.FAMILY_URI + "isSisterOf");
model.add(sara, relationProperty, paul);`

Comment: `private static Set<Property> collectRelationsProperties(Resource r, Model m) {
        java.util.Set<Property> result = new java.util.HashSet<>(10);
        StmtIterator it = r.listProperties();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Property property = it.nextStatement().getPredicate();
            if (property.getURI().contains(Ontology.FAMILY_URI) && Dal.getNameFromURI(property.getURI()).startsWith("is")) {
                result.add(property);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }`

Comment: please just update your question body, difficult to read big code in comments

Comment: Just do a clean experiment as I told, without any water. If you're lucky, you'll know where you're wrong, otherwise nobody will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a problem of entailment as I suspected. The problem was with the **OntModelSpec** used to create the OntModel.

I was using : `OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();`

According to Jena doc, it answers

> a new ontology model which will process in-memory models of ontologies
>   expressed the default ontology language (**OWL**)

I have changed to `OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);`

Jena doc says it

> uses a specification for **OWL DL** models that are stored in memory and
>   **do no additional entailment reasoning**

Now, only the DIRECT relation `isSisterOf` is return by `Resource#listProperties`

@ssz Thank you for your replies that push me to look at my problem with new eyes.

Comment: it would be nice if you clean the original question: add a good code in a single snippet, starting from constructing model and loading data, and short demostration, just like this: `listProperties().forEachRemaining(System.out::println)`. Calling method interacting json is irrelevant, sophisticated old-style collecting method - also.

Comment: Done. Thank you @ssz